# How do I manually replicate a Node.js buffer?

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have this buffer: `<Buffer 0d 0a>` and I am wondering how I can replicate it so I can test against it.

With `<Buffer 00>` I was able to do `new Buffer([00])` but when I do `new Buffer([0d 0a])` or `new Buffer([0d, 0a])` I get an error.

```
_0d0a = new Buffer([0d 0a]);
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Any help?

Update:

I need to create the buffer and not copy it as a stream I'm listening to sends the buffer I am looking for.

Comment: Console.log shows some text representation of buffer. It's not how you could create one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those bytes are shown as numbers in hexadecimal. To enter them into JavaScript, you need to prefix them with `0x`:

```
var CRLF = new Buffer([0x0d, 0x0a]);
```

Alternatively you can create a buffer from a string of hex:

```
var CRLF = new Buffer('0d0a', 'hex');
```

Note that this will throw an error (“TypeError: Invalid hex string”) if the string contains spaces or other characters, but you can remove those first:

```
var CRLF = new Buffer('0d 0a'.replace(/\W/g, ''), 'hex');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is considered the 'canonical' way, but it works:

```js
buff1 = new Buffer("hi there!");
buff2 = new Buffer(buff1.length);

buff1.copy(buff2);
console.log(buff2.toString()); // hi there!
```

Answer (score 1):

By the API docs at http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html, the most straightforward seems to be:

```
var copy = new Buffer(existing.length);
existing.copy(copy)
```

The `copy` will be a Buffer containing the copy of the contents of the Buffer `existing`.